Firebase push notification using node js server
I am looking to develop a method to send notification to flutter app via my node.js server. (httpv1)
I managed to test via postman. while doing from node.js server how to make things dynamic. How to get the authorization token dynamically and how to update it when it expires?

You may want to see the quickstart app for FCM using Node.js and make it as reference. There's a sample code implementation on how to get access token using service account and build the request to send notification.

will it handle the token expire on its own
